# How to pass a reference to a Javascript function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am building a table using DataTables, and it uses AJAX for it's data source. However, I can't seem to pass a function into the AJAX parameters; the $.post() function (from regular JQuery) always sends whatever my variable evaluates to when the page is loaded. I am pretty bad with understanding the inner workings of JS, so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Here is my code:

```
function init_datatable() {

  var url = null;
  var datasource = null;

  // Set AJAX url and data based on which page we're on
  if (window.location.pathname.indexOf("bookmarks") > -1) {
    url = "/bookmarks";
    datasource = bookmarks;
  } else {
    url = "/search";
    datasource = $('#form').serialize();
  }

  var table = $('#table').DataTable({
    "ajax" : function (data, callback, settings) {
      $.post(url, datasource, function (data) {
        callback(data);
      });
    }
  });
}
```

If I write `$.post(url, $("#form").serialize())` directly, without passing in the `serialize()` function inside the variable datasource, I get the expected result; every time the form changes, the updated data is included in the POST request. However, if I do it as written above, datasource is a static object of what the form contained at page load. I have also tried doing

```
datasource = function() {
  $("#form").serialize()
}
```

but this does not seem to work. How can I use datasource as both as a static global object and as a function that needs to be run every time `$.post()` is called, depending on the current page?

Comment: Because you only read it when the page is loaded. You would need to move it inside!

Answer (score 0):

Your initial if is called once. That's the problem.
It needs to be calculated in each post.

Put it within a function called getdatasource(), which returns it,
and call it initially and for every post :)

Answer (score 0):

shouldn't this be working

```
function init_datatable() {
    function datasource() {
        var url = null;
        var data = null;
        // Set AJAX url and data based on which page we're on
        if (window.location.pathname.indexOf("bookmarks") > -1) {
            url = "/bookmarks";
            data = bookmarks;
        } else {
            url = "/search";
            data = $('#form').serialize();
        }
        return [url, data];
    }

    var table = $('#table').DataTable({
        "ajax": function (data, callback, settings) {
            $.post(datasource()[0], datasource()[1], function (data) {
                callback(data);
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you declare `var datasource = null` in the first lines of your function, you are declaring that variable in that function's scope, as well as any scopes nested within it.

To update the `datasource` variable inside DataTable's ajax callback you just need to move your `$('#form').serialize();` line inside the callback, per the example below. That way the variable will also be set in your top-level function's scope (`init_datatable`).

```
function init_datatable() {

  var url = null;
  var datasource = null;

  // Set AJAX url and data based on which page we're on
  if (window.location.pathname.indexOf("bookmarks") > -1) {
    url = "/bookmarks";
    datasource = bookmarks;
  } else {
    url = "/search";
  }

  var table = $('#table').DataTable({
    "ajax" : function (data, callback, settings) {
      // each time this executes your top-level datasource variable
      // will be updated here
      datasource = $('#form').serialize();

      $.post(url, datasource, function (data) {
        callback(data);
      });
    }
  });
}
```